# why only 1000 records are read from a very large csv file using php?

Tags: php, csv, count

I am just learning to use PHP as a requirement came up at my work and I am trying to figure out why out of 124938 records in my CSV file only 1011 records are being read. Here is the very basic code that I am using.

```
<?php
print "<table>\n";
$fp = fopen('STDPRICE_FULL.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {
  print '<tr>';
  for ($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++) {
    print '<td>'.$csv_line[$i].'</td>';
  }
  print "</tr>\n";
} 
print '</table>\n';
fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
?>
```

When I print the count($csv_line) it shows me 1011 records only.
Now I believe it had something to do with the size of the integer maybe, but I am not sure.
Also, I searched ways to increase the size of the integer but PHP seems to handle type conversions on its own.
Can anyone suggest what I can do to read all the lines from the CSV file?

Comment: This might be some kind of memory issue since those are a lot of records. What's your php memory limit and script execution time?

Comment: `$j = count($csv_line);` --- so what's this? Like, why do you think it's a number of rows/records?

Comment: @Martin Konecny: why did you delete your perfectly valid answer?

Comment: It depends on how long the lines in your CSV file are. If they're longer than 1024 characters, you may lose data.

Comment: change `fgetcsv($fp,1024)` to `fgetcsv($fp)`.  Generally, you don't want to set the 2nd arg unless you have regular, expected (max) width rows in your file

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php. Just use fgetcsv($ftp)

Comment: I changed fgetcsv($fp,1024) to fgetcsv($fp) but its still the same.

Comment: My php.ini file has following                                                   max_input_vars = 6000
max_execution_time = 5000
memory_limit = 256M

Comment: Also I have uploaded the php file for you guys to look at the code. http://toorakcomputerservices.com.au/STDPRICE_FULL.php

Comment: Sounds like a memory limit was hit. If it keeps failing on the exact number of rows, maybe a specific line is killing it (ie: line has too many chars). Split the job up into batches of maybe 500 per batch.

Comment: When `$csv_line` becomes `false`, check where the file pointer is at using `ftell($fp)` and then inspect that line ... it's possible there's an issue with the CSV data itself.

Comment: i'm gonna ask the stupid question here.. are you *sure* you are pointing to the right file? Because when I view-source of your link, I see closing `</table>` tag so that to me says the `while` loop completed and there's no memory issues stopping script short, etc.. perhaps some editor you are viewing the file in is incorrectly showing data as more lines than there are (e.g. issues with `\r` vs. `\r\n` vs. `\n` vs. whatever system/editor you're viewing it on)

Comment: I will try with another editor and see if it works.

Comment: well, the "easier" thing to do would be compare the last item output to the last thing in the file.. do they match? `Photoshop Extended ALL IE ALL 300 000 plus Gold 2Y 24 Months PRO` that's the last thing I see before the final closing `</td></tr></table>` on your page.  Is that the last thing in your file?

Comment: It seems my cpanel upload of csv file does not copy the entire file. As I can see the same csv file with different  size in my computer and on cpanel after upload. I tried uploading several times but the size is still different.Now I am trying to upload via ftp but it is very slow due to the size of file. Maybe it will work and than i will try to run php file again.

Comment: After upload finished, I also changes the memory limit to 512M. Now it is working correctly and fetching all the records. Thank you all for troubleshooting that.

Comment: can you post what's on the lines 1010, 1011 and 1012? at least, can you check if there's any "," or backslash or something like that?

Comment: Well the csv file is so large it kind of turns in to black screen when i scroll at the bottom of the resulting page and the page ultimately crashes. http://toorakcomputerservices.com.au/STDPRICE.php . I may have to split the job in to batches as suggested by @WadeShuler . I am not sure how to do that but that seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: For me personally, it was a malformed csv causing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ParseCSV class.  We've used for really large files with great success.

[ParseCSV Class at GitHub](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php)

It has handled many issues we've had processing CSV files in PHP.

Answer (score -2):

Use that http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html.

Then work with Database.